# Pass website URL from Tableview to webview

Tags: uitableview, ios4, uiwebview

HI I have created a NSMutablArray and add 8 objects to it in the RootViewController. I am displaying the array in the tableview. Whenever i click on the cell with a certain name, i want to pass a URL to the webview which is currently part of anothe DetailViewController.

In that detail view controller,the respective web page has to be displayed.

---

*Added from a comment*

I wrote this code in didselect row at indexpath

```
CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0); 
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame]; 
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
NSString *urlAddress = @"h.com";; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]; 
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[webView loadRequest:requestObj]; 
[self.view addSubview:webView]; 
[webView release];
```

My array name is listofitems, so how can i directly call my array into the url address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DetailsViewController *viewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] 
  initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

[viewController setUrl:actualUrl];
```

where actualUrl is the value in your rootViewController & create another variable url in detailViewController

Comment: I Wrote this code in didselect row at indexpath

CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
 UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
 [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 NSString *urlAddress = @"http://herbsforhealth.com";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
 [self.view addSubview:webView]; 
 [webView release];


my array name is listofitems,so how can i directly call my array into the url address.Please help me in this

Comment: in the above code i am getting static webpage for every row . I want to take that dynamically.so can i call my array directly in the line    NSString *urladdress=@"http://%@",get listofitems;  like this can i do.If yes what is the right way to call my array

Comment: where you are adding the webview.I mean where you are writing the code for webView

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Don't forget that you can edit your question or your answer, and if you put 4 spaces before a line of text it gets formatted as code (or select you code and click the {} button above the editing area, or put backticks ` around your code). Makes it much more readable and helpful for people looking for answers in the future.